# Как создать в строке еще один столбец?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

У меня есть массив из 4 строк и 1 столбца:

```
[[[476 161]]

 [[504 312]]

 [[535 320]]

 [[532 183]]]
```

Мне нужно получить 4 строки и 2 столбца, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
[[[476, 161]]

 [[504, 312]]

 [[535, 320]]

 [[532, 183]]]
```

Планирую потом обращаться непосредственно к отдельным значениям, например:

```
print (a[0][1])
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: У вас в первом случае одномерный массив, во втором двумерный.
Вам нужно будет написать функцию-маппер, переводящую из одного массива в другой

Comment: Я думал об этом но не могу реализовать, не могли бы вы показать как сделать правильно?

Comment: Как вы получили данный массив? Это случайно не Numpy Array?

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю, Ваш исходный одномерный массив строк (на самом деле, судя по количеству скобок - список одноэлементных списков) выглядит так:

```
one_dim_list = [['476 161',], ['504 312',], ['535 320',], ['532 183',]]
```

То, что нужно сделать - каждый его элемент разделить на две строки при помощи метода `split()`:

```
two_dim_list = [el[0].split() for el in one_dim_list]
```

Теперь можно к двумерному списку обращаться по индексам, как Вы хотели:

```
print(two_dim_list[0][1])
```

---

Возможно, что исходный список выглядит на самом деле так:

```
one_dim_list = ['476 161', '504 312', '535 320', '532 183']
```

Тогда двумерный будет получен так:

```
two_dim_list = [el.split() for el in one_dim_list]
```

---

Кстати, если нужно получить двумерный список чисел, а не строк, то второй способ превращается в

```
two_dim_list_int = [
    [int(number) for number in el.split()] for el in one_dim_list
]
```

---

Если речь об `numpy.array` то

```
b = numpy.array([
    [[476, 161]],
    [[504, 312]],
    [[535, 320]],
    [[532, 183]]
])
```

то массив, на самом деле, трёхмерный, и обращаться надо по трём индексам, причём размерности такие:

```
print(b.shape) # (4, 1, 2)
print(b[0][0][0]) # 476
```

**А лучше [написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/854144/247581) MaxU**

Comment: `[['476 161',], ['504 312',], ['535 320',], ['532 183',]]` зачем запятые после значений?

Comment: К сожалению при использовании этого метода выдает ошибку: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @Alban, честно говоря, мне просто почему-то так удобнее

Comment: @MikhailKUZ можете добавить тогда демонстрацию, откуда взялось такое значение? Я просто сначала подумал, что строка - это тип из Python

Answer (score 1):

исходный 3D массив:

```
In [32]: a = np.array([
    ...:     [[476, 161]],
    ...:     [[504, 312]],
    ...:     [[535, 320]],
    ...:     [[532, 183]]
    ...: ])
    ...:

In [33]: print(a)
[[[476 161]]

 [[504 312]]

 [[535 320]]

 [[532 183]]]

In [34]: print(a.shape)
(4, 1, 2)
```

преобразование в 2D массив:

```
In [35]: a = a.reshape(4, -1)

In [36]: print(a)
[[476 161]
 [504 312]
 [535 320]
 [532 183]]

In [37]: print(a.shape)
(4, 2)

In [38]: print(a[1,1])
312

In [39]: print(a[1:3, 0:2])
[[504 312]
 [535 320]]
```

PS возможно вам стоит ознакомиться с [Numpy Tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html)